# AndroidStudio install on Chromebook - crouton-Skript Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, chromebook, arm

I bought a Chromebook from Acer with an ARM-Architecture (ARM7 => 32bit, i think)

I want to program in Android-Studio.

So I downloaded it and tried to install, but it didn't work.

The error-message is `Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool`

After research i know that the problem is with 64bit-Architecture and I have to install the 32bit libs

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

I cant install these libs. I think that the reason is my ARM-Architecture.

Has anyone an idea to solve the Problem?

My operating system:

ACER ChromeBook ARM7-Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (upgraded from 12.04 LTS)
installed by crouton-script

Thanks a lot and i hope you understand my problem. Sorry for my bad English. I couldn't find any solution in German or English.

Comment: try this command `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: i tried, packages error : "unable to locate package"

Comment: Did you use `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` before that ?

Comment: yes, same error messages

Comment: Open "Software Sources" (or Software & Updates in 13.04+) by searching for it in the Dash.
Open the "Ubuntu Software" tab.
Ensure that the first 4 check boxes on this tab are enabled

Comment: i couldnt find it. i think it isnt in this ubuntu-version installed by croutonSkript. i think u use the same kernel which the ChromeOS is using.

Comment: Don't you find software sources ? Do you use unity desktop or other desktop environment ?

Comment: I don't think it's kernel issue

Comment: i use xfce for the ubuntu =)

Comment: do this "gksu software-center" on terminal and let me know what's happen

Comment: nothing =( =/  ...

Comment: okay post the `nano etc/apt/sources.list` output

Comment: deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible as Android SDK is not available pre-compiled for ARM, only for x86(64) architecture.
In theory, Android Studio should work as its Java, but I suspect it has native executable (.so) library dependencies as well as they would need to be recompiled for ARM as well trying to run Android Studio on a HP Chromebook 14 (Tegra K1 based) with ubuntu installed crouton and openjdk installed via apt just causes the java exe to stop - not error message or segfault, just does nothing.